# Accesing static variable from another class in java

Tags: java, class, static, public

I had a queue implemented as linked list in my multithreaded server. I want to access this queue from another class. Both classes are in the same package. I tried making this queue as public static and accessing it through getter, but without success Can somebody tell me what is the exact problem.

This is my code:
Queue Declaration:

```
public static Queue<Request> q=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Request>();

public static void setQ(Queue<Request> q) {
        Connection.q = q;
    }

    public static Queue<Request> getQ() {
        return q;
    }
```

Accesing Queue:

```
Queue<Request> queue=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Request>(); 
queue=Connection.getQ();
```

Adding Value to Queue in thread of connection

```
q.add(r);
```

Comment: post the relevant parts of your code please

Comment: Also what is the actual problem you are having? Explain "without success". Is it compilation problems or run-time?

Comment: Be aware of using non thread-safe queues on multithreaded program. Have a look at [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) if you haven't already, it might help you.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

You can access a `public static` member of another class directly, using the notation `ClassName.memberName`:

```
public class Foo {
    public static String bar = "hi there";
}

public class Thing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Foo.bar); // "hi there"
   }
}
```

`public static` data members are usually not a great idea (unless they've `final`), but if you need one, that's how you do it.

Comment: Hi T.J. may I ask that in this case, is Foo itself becomes an object in Foo.bar? I come from JavaScript and when using Math.PI, everybody says Math is a math object, but in Java, people I meet just say "You can access a static var via its class name", so I got confused. Thanks!

Comment: @Hang - `Foo` isn't an object in Java, no. (As you know, it would be an object -- specifically a constructor function -- in JavaScript.) Classes are a first-class concept in Java. There *is* an object that represents the class `Foo` (an instance of `Class` you can access via `Foo.class`), but `Foo` itself isn't an object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply T.J.! Then what should we call Foo in Foo.bar if it's not a object nor a class? It seems hard to find this answer explicitly in any source...

Comment: @Hang - It's just the class name. More in the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-6.html

Comment: Oh gotcha! I see it in 6.1. Declarations. I appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access if directly, or using static getter methods...

If this is your Queue class...

```
public class Queue {
    public static LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();

    public static ListedList getMyList(){
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Then you could access your list be either calling `Queue.myList` or `Queue.getMyList()` - both will do the same thing. The benefit of using a getter method would be that you can control access to the list, such as by making the method `synchronized`, preventing calls to the list being out of order.

Comment: I tried this two things. But i am getting the queue empty. Following are snippets of my code. In server class i am creating connection class object and creating new connection in new thread. In connection I declared queue as:

Comment: Could you please paste your code in your question so that is can be formatted correctly.

Comment: Queue declaration:                                               public static Queue<Request> q=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Request>();                                                                                                      public static void setQ(Queue<Request> q) {
  Connection.q = q;
}                                                                     public static Queue<Request> getQ() {
  return q;
 }

Comment: Adding value to queue in run method of thread:                   getQ().add(r);                                                                                                                          and accesing queue in this way:                        Queue<Request> queue=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Request>(); 
       queue=Connection.getQ();