# Java class to class actions and calls

Tags: java

I am trying to implement actions in Lab5.java by callling upon a JComboBox and getting its selected value (or index, will work either way) from Lab4.java. When I make a variable in Lab5

```
int ind = cbb.getSelectedIndex();
```

where cbb is the JComboBox.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab5 extends Lab4 implements ActionListener
{
    //private int numClicks = 0;
    int ind = cbb.getSelectedIndex();
   public void init()
   {
        super.init();
        addListeners();
        this.setSize(getPreferredSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
 //     numClicks++;
 //     System.out.println(numClicks);
        if (ind == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(ind);
            createFrame();

        }else {


        }

    }
    public void addListeners() 
    {

    }
}
 Here is my Lab5 file. 

    JComboBox cbb = new JComboBox();
    cbb.addItem("Set Destination                     ");
    cbb.addItem("Dallas");
    cbb.addItem("Wash DC");
    cbb.addItem("Seattle");
    cbb.addItem("Oklahoma City");
    cbb.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
```

Here is how my combobox is declared and linked to my actionPerformed. It returns the error on Lab5 that "cbb cannot be resolved to a variable". Where can I learn how to call on variables or components in one Java class to have actions performed on it in a second Java class ?

Comment: Methods. Getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int ind = cbb.getSelectedIndex();
```

cbb has not been declared as a variable in that class.

You could set a variable in the Lab5 class as **static** and access from the path ***Lab5.variable*** as seen here:

[Accesing static variable from another class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279553/accesing-static-variable-from-another-class-in-java)

Or you could use getters and setters when instantiate in your class Lab4.
Like:

```
// code inserted in Lab 4
Lab5 obj = new Lab5();
obj.getVariable();
```

I think you need to start at the basics in Java to understand how OOP works.

Comment: You're completely right. I am taking intro to programming right now at my college and the professor will not teach us the things we need to know to do this.

Comment: I recommend using the vast material on internet to start from the ground/basics. The book Java How to program is an excellent book also.
Do not forget to upvote the right answer choosing the one who best fits our question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than any other objects talking to each other. One object needs a reference to another in order to invoke methods on that other object.

For example, let's say we're going to build a class to represent an animal shelter. In this shelter we're going to have many instances of animals.

So the `Animal` class may look something like this:

```
package objectsTalking;

public class Animal {
    private int age;

    public Animal(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

The `AnimalShelter` will provide the ability to obtain the average age of animals currently in the shelter. So it may look something like this:

```
package objectsTalking;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class AnimalShelter {
    private Collection<Animal> animals;

    public AnimalShelter(){
        animals = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(Animal animal){
        animals.add(animal);
    }

    public int getAverageAge(){
        int total = 0;
        for(Animal animal: animals){
            total += animal.getAge();
        }

        if(animals.isEmpty())
            return total;
        return total/animals.size();
    }
}
```

Lastly we need a controller class to house our `main` method and act as the entry point and overseer. I simply called this class `Main`:

```
package objectsTalking;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalShelter shelter = new AnimalShelter();
        shelter.add(new Animal(6));
        shelter.add(new Animal(2));
        shelter.add(new Animal(1));
        shelter.add(new Animal(3));

        System.out.println(shelter.getAverageAge());
    }

}
```

Notice how the `Main` class creates the `shelter` and adds the animals to it. It talks to the `shelter` simply by invoking methods that the `AnimalShelter` class provides. Similarly the shelter talks to its animals by invoking methods that the `Animal` class provides. You would do the same thing with your objects - provide methods to expose the behaviors you want other objects to access.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely use your examples for reference.